# Is asp.net responsible for this anchor tag repeating?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Notice in the top picture there is an anchor that is only in the source once. But when the page is rendered, you can see in the bottom picture where I've highlighted the 5 places this anchor tag is repeated. Why does it do this?

If the answer is "it's probably something in your javascript/jquery causing this" then I can accept that as a valid answer. I don't think that's the case, but I at least want to rule out whether this is some odd but not unexpected behavior from MVC.

[image: Cshtml]

[image: Page Source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I already managed to more or less answer this for myself. I didn't realize a self closing anchor tag is not technically valid html. After I adjusted it to have a closing tag then it rendered as expected.

I'm a bit surprised that the asp engine couldn't figure this out though... had it just rendered as is it would have likely been interpreted well enough by any browser. And if Microsoft wanted to try to "fix" my mistake it's pretty stinking clear all that was needed was to add a closing tag immediately after and be done with it. So I can't answer why the heck Microsoft would have this behavior but at least now I can say it was definitely Microsoft's doing.